# JSON data problem

Tags: java, json, web-applications, jakarta-ee, jersey

I am implementing RESTful Jersey application.

If I have a **car** bean:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Car{
  private String id;
  private String name;

  //... GETTER & SETTER 
}
```

My CarResource.java:

```
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<Car> getCar(@QueryParam("id") String id) {


        List cars= new ArrayList<Car>();

        cars.add(new Car(id, "my car 1"));

        return cars;
    }
```

If there is **only one element** in the `cars` list, the JSON data I got is

```
{"car":{"id":"12","name":"my car 1"}}
```

But what I need is (with "**[ ]**"):

```
{"car":[{"id":"12","name":"my car 1"}]}
```

How to do?

P.S. if there are **more than one** element in the `cars` list, the JSON data do have "**[ ]**".

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to handle this JavaScript-side.

Assuming you've parsed your data into a JavaScript object, try something like the following to get the items:

```
function GetCar(pObj, nPos){
    if (typeof pObj.car[0] === "object"){
        return pObj.car[nPos];
    } else {
        return pObj.car;
    }
}

//test code
var obj = {"car":{"id":"12","name":"my car 1"}};
var obj2 = {"car":[{"id":"12","name":"my car 1"}]};

alert(GetCar(obj, 0).id);
alert(GetCar(obj2, 0).id);
```

You can see it in action at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rV9sc/)

Comment: Ok... so, no way to get rid of it on server side??

Answer (score 0):

I use the following script in javascript to parse the json data (even if it has one or more records)

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

If you can convert the core code used in that script to parse then u can handle that situation

Comment: I would like to seek a way to always have [] in my json data before it is touched by javascript, but thank you.